# Determine subsets among members of a powerset efficiently in Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, bin, powerset

So I've indexed the members of the powerset of the alphabet in the following way:

```
def bytecode_index(some_subset):
    mask = 0
    for index in bytearray(some_subset):
        mask |= (1<<(index-97))
    return mask
```

This might be a bit nonstandard, and improvements with respect to improving it are very much welcome, but the crux of my question is actually as follows:

How can I take two such masks and determine if one is a subset of the other efficiently and pythonically?  One such way for determining if `index1` is a subset of `index2` is to compare their binary strings.  if `index1` has a 1 where `index2` has a 0, the set corresponding to `index1`is not a subset of the set corresponding to `index2`.

I've written something that looks like this for that:

```
def compare_binary_strings(index1,index2):

    return not any(x == "1" and y == "0" for x,y in zip(bin(index1), bin(index2)))
```

This seems inefficient, as it involves converting the indices to strings and then comparing them componentwise.  Any and all help is much appreciated.

Is there a more simple operation available to quickly compare the two indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't know about Pythonically, but generically the way to check if one bitmask is a subset of the other is:

```
(x & y) == x
```

Iff true, `x` is a subset of `y`.

This just the bitmath equivalent of the familiar

A ⊆ B ⇔ A ∩ B = A